# Disallow blank path in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have states defined in the form

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('school', _.extend({}, rootStateConfig, { url: '/school/:name}))
```

Problem is whenever we I hit `localhost/school/` it goes to the above defined state. how should i disallow null names?

Answer (score 1):

try to map that status before. Example:

```
$stateProvider
.state('schoolNew', _.extend({}, rootStateConfig, { url: '/school'}))
.state('school', _.extend({}, rootStateConfig, { url: '/school/:name'}))
```